# Удалить конкретное activity из стека

Tags: android, activity, стек

Как удалить конкретное activity из стека? вот пример, есть  activty A,B,C, пользователь переходит A->B->C, и в activty C в определенных условиях,

1. надо вернуться назад(activty B) (делаю finish)
2. надо вернуться назад(сразу в activty A минуя activty B, при этом не пересоздавая activty A, как это сделать?)

//делаю так, он пересоздает activty  A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Просто не храни в стеке B, onBackPressed переведет сразу в А, ну или finish() в зависимости что там есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Городить код с запуском активити через `onActivityResult()` - нерационально. Следует назначить активити А `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. И запустив
`startActivity(new Intent(this, A)` активити А вытащится из стека не пересоздаваясь, попутно закрыв верхние активити.

Answer (score 5):

Ответ на вопросы:

1. Что бы вернуться с активити С на В, ты все делаешь правильно, просто вызываешь finish() у активити С.
2. Что бы вернуться с С на А нужно немного добавить логики.
   Когда запускаешь активити С, делай это через:

   startActivtyForResult(new Intent(this, C.class), 1234)

При завершении С, перед вызовом finish(), в обратный интент кинь флаг нужно ли завершиться активити В или нет:

```
    Intent answerIntent = new Intent();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("need_finish", true);

    answerIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, answerIntent);
```

Активити В обрабатывает метод onActivityResult. Если флаг true, то тоже вызываешь finish() у В :

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){    
    if (requestCode == 1234 && data != null) {
        if (data.getBoolean("need_finish", true)) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```